# Spacy Matcher/PhraseMatcher Span, how to expand span to the current sentence?

Tags: spacy

I have a text :"Alphabet is a company. Also it is behind Google. But these are not the same".
Based on the spacy matcher when applied, it returns label, start, end in matches.
Now based on the start and end, is there a way I can expand the span to entire sentence(word which ends with period)?

```
{

    matches = self.matcher(doc)
            spans = []
            for label, start, end in matches:
                span = Span(doc, start, end, label=label)

}
```

So the output I am expecting is given below....

### Actual

```
Entities[('Alphabet','myORG'),('Google','myORG')]
```

### Expecting

```
Entities[('Alphabet is a company','myORG'),('Also it is behind Google','myORG')]
```

Code that I have used :

```
{

    from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function
    import plac
    from spacy.lang.en import English
    from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
    from spacy.tokens import Doc, Span, Token
    def main(text="Alphabet is a company. Also it is behind Google. But these are not the same", *companies):
        nlp = English()
        if not companies: 
            companies = ['Alphabet', 'Google', 'Netflix', 'Apple']
        component = myFindingsMatcher(nlp, companies)
        nlp.add_pipe(component, last=True)
        doc = nlp(text)
        print('Entities', [(e.text, e.label_) for e in doc.ents])  # all orgs are entities
    class myFindingsMatcher(object):
        name = 'myFindings_matcher'
        def __init__(self, nlp, companies=tuple(), label='myORG'):
            patterns = [nlp(finding_type) for finding_type in companies]
            self.matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
            self.matcher.add(label, None, *patterns)
        def __call__(self, doc):
            matches = self.matcher(doc)
            spans = []
            for label, start, end in matches:
                span = Span(doc, start, end, label=label)
                spans.append(span)
            doc.ents = spans
            return doc
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        plac.call(main)

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `e.sent` is used to refer to the sentence containing entity `e`.

Minimal working example with the pre-compiled model `en_core_web_sm` and its built-in Matcher:

```
my_text = "Alphabet is a company. Also it is behind Google. But these are not the same"
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp(my_text)
print('Entities', [(e.text, e.label_, e.sent) for e in doc.ents])
```

This produces

> Entities [('Alphabet', 'ORG', Alphabet is a company.), ('Google', 'ORG', Also it is behind Google.)]

If you want to implement your own matcher using `nlp = English()`, you will have to add a module to recognize sentences:

```
nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe('sentencizer'))
```

And you will have to make sure that the `e.sent` is set properly when defining entity spans. Note that you can easily deduce the correct span from looking at the sentence offsets (counting tokens):

```
print('Sentences', [(s.start, s.end, s.text) for s in doc.sents])
print('Entities', [(e.start, e.end, e.text, e.label_) for e in doc.ents])
```

Would print

> Sentences [(0, 5, 'Alphabet is a company.'), (5, 11, 'Also it is behind Google.'), (11, 17, 'But these are not the same')]
>
> Entities [(0, 1, 'Alphabet', 'ORG'), (9, 10, 'Google', 'ORG')]